Disable AutoFill, Speak and Spell for UITextField
I want to disable basically any actions with text in a UITextField. That also means user can't Speak, Spell or AutFill the content. Here's the code I'm using for my custom UITextField:
class GradientTextField: UITextField {
    var actionEnabled: Bool = true
...
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
        if actionEnabled {
            return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    override func selectionRects(for range: UITextRange) -> [UITextSelectionRect] {
        return []
    }
    
    override func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
        return .zero
    }

And yet it still does allow speaking, spelling & autofilling its content. Look at the screenshot below:

In addition, I want to prevent the user from using a cursor there. So symbol deletion and input are done in the same order (e.g. if I type in 1234, I cannot delete 3 or 2 to make it 14).
Could you help me find out how to do it?

A solution could be put a UIButton on top of UITextField to block interactions. So when user tap the button, all we have to do is make UITextField become first responder

class DisableTextField: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func onTap(_ sender: Any) {
        textfield.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

}


Really nice workaround! Never thought about that! Thank you!!!
